# Run expect spawned commands one after the another

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have written an expect script which I am calling from my bash script, which removes the content in the directories, copies the jar and extracts it. I am doing it through expect script shown below:

I have used sleep and wait between the process and nothing helps. I do not get the desired output as expected. Please check the script is fairly simple, it removes content inside the directory, created one, add jar and tries to extract it.

```
set timeout -1
set PASS [lindex $argv 0];
set DIRECTORY [lindex $argv 1];
set FOLDER_NAME [lindex $argv 2];
set WAR_PATH [lindex $argv 3];
set WAR_NAME [lindex $argv 4];
spawn sudo rm -rf $DIRECTORY/$FOLDER_NAME
expect "Password:"
send $PASS\r
spawn sudo mkdir $DIRECTORY/$FOLDER_NAME
expect "Password:"
send $PASS\r
spawn sudo cp $WAR_PATH $DIRECTORY/$FOLDER_NAME
expect "Password:"
send $PASS\r
spawn sudo jar -xf $DIRECTORY/$FOLDER_NAME/$WAR_NAME
expect "Password:"
send $PASS\r
set timeout -1
expect eof
exit 0
```

Please help me so that this process is completed one after another without any problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After *each* `send $PASS\r`, you should `expect eof` to wait for the spawned process to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.